# Wordpress .htaccess: AddDefaultCharset takes one argument, The name of the default charset to add to any Content-Type without one or 'Off' to disable

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress website, currently working fine but as soon as traffic hits, it shows Internal Server Error, unable to login, and shows 500 error.

When I check this in the log: this is the message, i'm seeing:

Apache Error Log:
**"public_html/.htaccess: AddDefaultCharset takes one argument, The name of the default charset to add to any Content-Type without one or 'Off' to disable"**

And as soon as i change the .htaccess file with new one, it start working again.

Normally it works fine, but as soon as i hit traffic, it goes down.

Below are current settings in the .htaccess file.

```
**<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddCharset UTF-8 .html .atom .css .js .json .rss .vtt .xml
</IfModule>**

**<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>**
```

I have more than 8gb with good storage, currently using wprocket and few more plugins but all are premium versions.

Could anyone please help me on this?

Thank you friends..

Comment: _“Below are current settings in the .htaccess file.”_ - in which the directive mentioned in the error message, is notably absent. Plus, a syntax error in the configuration, is a syntax error in the configuration - that in itself does not depend on “how much traffic” you currently have on your site. So there must be something else going on here. Maybe WP Rocket modifies the .htaccess to handle its serving of cached documents or something like that. (The .htaccess you have shown us, is the one the error message is referring to, yes?)

Comment: Error in htaccess usually mean the website won't work at all. This issue is probably a hosting side issue, which when hits traffic the server gets down, or else a plugin issue on your end. Both of which are difficult to pin point without debugging.